# Issue with active pointer on mobile, with Phaser 3

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to move my player by clicking on the right or left of the game. While everything is fine on the computer, when I try it on mobile it always moves to the right and after many attempts it starts moving to the left, no matter where press. This is my `update` function:

```
if (game.input.activePointer.isDown)
{
    if (game.input.mousePointer.x > 600)
    {
        player.setVelocityX(160);
        player.anims.play('right', true);
    }   
    else if (game.input.mousePointer.x < 200)
    {
        player.setVelocityX(-160);
        player.anims.play('left', true);
    }
} else {
    player.setVelocityX(0);
    player.anims.play('turn', true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using the `mousePointer` which will only look at the mouse.

From [the mousePointer documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.InputManager.html#mousePointer__anchor):

> The mouse has its own unique Pointer object, which you can reference directly if making a *desktop specific game*. If you are supporting both desktop and touch devices then do not use this property, instead use activePointer which will always map to the most recently interacted pointer.

Switch to [`activePointer`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.InputManager.html#activePointer__anchor) for all your logic and you should be set.

If you're using physics, which it appears you might be, the reason it's moving slightly may have to do with logic somewhere else in your code; that's the only reason I can think of given your `if` statements.

Comment: its works, i really apreciate it. Thank you so much. 
greetings from Argentina

Comment: Happy to help! :)